# Corrent passing arguments to docker entrypoint

Tags: bash, docker

I have a super dumb script

```sh
$ cat script.sh 
cat <<EOT > entrypoint.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@"
EOT

docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/entrypoint.sh:/root/entrypoint.sh --entrypoint /root/entrypoint.sh bash:4 Hello World
```

But when I run script I got strange error:

```
$ sh script.sh 
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Why script does not print `Hello world` ?

Comment: `chmod +x entrypoint.sh`?

Comment: @AnthonySottile that's correct, but you would have seen a `permission denied` error if the script would not have had the executable bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

The above error means one of:

- Your script actually doesn't exist. This isn't likely with your volume mount but it doesn't hurt to run the container without the entrypoint, just open a shell with the same volume mount and list the file to be sure it's there. It's possible for the volume mount to fail on desktop versions of docker where the directory isn't shared to the docker VM and you end up with empty folders being created inside the container instead of mounting your file. When checking from inside of another container, also make sure you have execute permissions on the script.
- If it's a script, the first line pointing to the interpreter is invalid. Make sure that command exists inside the container. E.g. alpine containers typically do not ship with bash and you need to use `/bin/sh` instead. This is the most common issue that I see.
- If it's a script, similar to above, make sure your first line has linux linefeeds. A windows linefeed adds and extra `\r` to the name of the command trying to be run, which won't be found on the linux side.
- If the command is a binary, it can refer to a missing library. I often see this with "statically" compiled go binaries that didn't have CGO disabled and have links to libc appear when importing networking libraries.
- If you use json formatting to run your command, I often see this error with invalid json syntax. This doesn't apply to your use case, but may be helpful to others googling this issue.

This list is pulled from a talk I gave at last year's DockerCon: https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2018/faq-stackoverflow.html#59

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

**Request**

```
 docker run -it --rm bash:4 which bash
```

**Output**

> /usr/local/bin/bash

So

```
 #!/bin/bash
```

Should be changed to

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

And

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/entrypoint.sh:/root/entrypoint.sh --entrypoint /root/entrypoint.sh bash:4 Hello World
```

Gives you

> Hello World

**Update**

Code

```
cat <<EOT > entrypoint.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@"
EOT
```

Should be fixed as

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat <<EOT > entrypoint.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "\$@"
EOT
```

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is more portable and flexible

Comment: @Dmitrii Sh*t, I haven't thought than location of bash could be different in alpine, thanks. However if I change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` I still don't see `Hello world`, output is empty string. What could be another problem?

Comment: Yes, there is a problem, typical for bash) I fixed it in the main answer.

Comment: I meaned even if I follow your fixed guide it's still not working

Comment: can u show output of docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/entrypoint.sh:/root/entrypoint.sh bash:4 ls -l /root/, and docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/entrypoint.sh:/root/entrypoint.sh bash:4 cat /root/entrypoint.sh ?

Comment: 1) `-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000            28 Mar 15 11:43 entrypoint.sh` 2) `#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo ""
`. So problem is that symbol `$@` is not printing correctly for some reason.

Comment: Have u seen this fix: 'echo "\$@"'? it's not a problem, $ - take the value, so 'echo "" ' - the result of the upstream script. u need to escape & by taken \$

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought if I print file using `cat <<EOT` it's never resolve to real value that's why I forgot to make escaping. Thanks so much for pointing me :)